# What is this line of code ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity, wif

I find in a code example downloaded the following line of code in an Action method of a controller.
**ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name") or probably its async version 
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Id", "Name");**

I am not able to fathom whats happening here. Also in the corresponding view, I nowhere see ViewBag.RoleId being used. Instead I find in the view
**@Html.DropDownList("RoleId","No Roles")**

There appears to be some trivial connection between the two. Can someone throw some light at whet I am missing.

The following is the line of code in the action method.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    //Get the list of Roles
    ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(await RoleManager.Roles.ToListAsync(), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

And the corresponding view is as follows.

```
@model AspnetIdentitySample.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
        <legend>Create a new user.</legend>
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HomeTown, new { @class = "control-label" })
            <div class="controls">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HomeTown)
            </div>
        </div>
        <h4>Select Role for User</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.DropDownList("RoleId","No Roles")
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged "wif". "wif" is not "asp.net identity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name")
```

is creating a `SelectList` used by the `@Html.DropDownList()` or `@Html.DropDownListFor()` helpers to render the options in a `<select>` tag. The options will have a `value`attribute defined by the `Id` property of `Role` and a display text defined by the `Name` property.

The view is using

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoleId","No Roles")
```

which binds to ViewData property `RoleId` (the `ViewBag` property) and the second argument renders an option label (the first option will have no value, but display the text "No Roles"

This is not a good usage, and it is recommended you use strongly typed helpers to bind to your model properties.

```
ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name")

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleID, (SelectList)ViewBag.RoleList,"No Roles")
```

where `RoleID` is a property in the model that will be bound to the selected options value

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks beginning to understand.