# Adding AspNetUserRoles in Registration MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have added two roles to the AspNetRoles table (Owner, Contractor)

After reading some threads on here I have added the code to add the user to a specific role (Owner):

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email};
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Owner");
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

What I would like to do is add a group of unchecked radio buttons bound to the AspNetRoles table on the registration screen and based on the users selection add them to that role.

How do I access the current roles in the AspNetRoles table in the registration view?

UPDATE: I have tried to add the roles to a viewbag on the controller:

```
ViewBag.RoleList = new SelectList(RoleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name")
```

however I get the following error:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager<TRole,TKey>' requires 2 type arguments
```

This was based on another post and marked as the answer.

Comment: can you show RoleManager property code in your controller?

Comment: I'm not sure as I am pretty new to MVC. I found the example in this thread [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26800310/what-is-this-line-of-code-viewbag-roleid-new-selectlistrolemanager-roles-id)

Comment: so you are using default MVC5 template?

Comment: Yep. Straight out the box

Answer (score 0):

Controller fragment:

```
RolesList = RoleManager.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = userRoles.Contains(x.Name),
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Name
            }
```

In the model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }
```

In the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Label("Roles", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <span class=" col-md-10">
            @foreach (var item in Model.RolesList)
            {
                        <input type="checkbox" name="SelectedRole" value="@item.Value" checked="@item.Selected" class="checkbox-inline" />
                        @Html.Label(item.Value, new { @class = "control-label" })
            }
        </span>
</div>
```

Found a good example here but it is a bit complicated. The above summarizes the relevant fragments: [RolesExample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790720/ASP-NET-Identity-Customizing-Users-and-Roles)

Comment: I added the model line fine however the controller is not working. Firstly it the RolesList does not exist in the current context so I added var in front as I guess we are creating a new list. I am now stuck on an error with RoleManager: 'Using the generic type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.RoleManager<TRole>' requires 1 type arguments'

Comment: I can't seem to figure this out. At present I only have two roles so I have opted for a fixed radio button group, passing in the select value to assign as the role.